# Why is the NLA Editor the Only Animation Editor in 2.8 Without a Hotkey?

Tags: interface, nla-editor

For some reason, when I click on the "Editor Type" button which appears to the left of any editor window header, the resulting editor window popup flickers and disappears as soon as my mouse is moved afterwards (probably a problem with my mouse and not Blender). So, as a workaround to this weirdness, I decided to familiarize myself with the editor window hotkeys, as this would bypass the problem by giving me access to the editor windows without the need for clicks. This works for all animation editors fine, provided I can remember the shortcuts, such as Shift-F6 for the Graph Editor/Driver Editor, etc. But the NLA has no such shortcut listed. I did some research and discovered that there was once such a shortcut in previous versions of Blender (Shift-Ctrl-F12 or something like that). I was going to try to create such a shortcut in 2.8 manually, but there would appear to be no way to right-click in the Editor Window popup and create a shortcut there. Where else would I create such a shortcut, using the UI? Failing a UI method, how else might I create a shortcut for the NLA editor window? Is there a preference file that I can edit manually? I'm running 2.82a on Ubunto Studio 19.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Edit > Preferences... > Keymap > Window` you'll find the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F*</kbd> shortcuts as "Cycle Space Type Set". Open up one you don't use and change its type to "Nonlinear Animation". Or you can create a new shortcut and set it to `screen.space_type_set_or_cycle`, then add the type.

[image]

Comment: I get as far as Keymap > Window, and then find that I can't follow any of your other instructions. "You'll find the Shift+F shortcuts..." I don't find them. "... as Cycle Space Type Set." I don't see that either. "Or you could create a new shortcut and..." This is exactly what I'm asking how to do in the OP. "... set it to screen.space_type_set_or_cycle..." I have no idea what this is or what its in reference to.

Comment: okay, under the window drop down, what do you see? do you have entries with the first one being "New file", then "Open recent", then some more?

Comment: added a gif, hopefully that'll help you

Comment: @R-800 any luck?

Comment: It took a while, but I finally figured it out. It wasn't straightforward at all. I think it's really something how I had to paste that cryptic string "screen.space_type_set_or_cycle before I could get access to the NLA as a mappable target. But even after getting that far, it wasn't smooth sailing. Turns out that I was adding a key modifier when I had only intended to add the main keypress, and so this modifier was being required along with the main keypress every time. The tooltip for the main keypress says "Type of Event." That is probably not the clearest choice of words.

Comment: @R-800 yep, I agree. Keymaps are such a pain to work with, wish it was easier.